# inserting two rows with paired id mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, match

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM match ORDER BY id ASC
```

The results will have these:

```
ID Name   Age
1  Mary   18
2  Edward 18
3  Jen    22
```

I want to pair Mary and Edward because they have the same age:
The expected result will be:

```
1. Mary
      ID 1 Age 18 match to ID 2 Edward Age 18
2. Edward
      ID 2 Age 18 match to ID 1 Mary Age 18
3. Jen
      ID 3 Age 22 match to no pair
```

I want to insert the pair two times in a row with corresponding pair.

Here is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM match ORDER BY id ASC");
$size_of_array = sizeof($result);
$i = 1;
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
     $pair_A  = $data[0];
     while ($i <= $size_of_array) {
            $pair_B  = $data[$i];

            $insert_A = array(
                              'id'  =>  $pair_A['id'],
                              'name' => $pair_A['name'],
                              'age'  => $pair_A['age'],
                              'partnerName' => $pair_B['name'],
                              'partnerAge'  => $pair_B['age']
                              'partnerID'   => $pair_B['id']
                              );
            //insert statement 1
            $insert_B = array(
                              'id'  =>  $pair_B['id'],
                              'name' => $pair_B['name'],
                              'age'  => $pair_B['age'],
                              'partnerName' => $pair_A['name'],
                              'partnerAge'  => $pair_A['age']
                              'partnerID'   => $pair_A['id']
                              );
            //insert statement 2

            //Remove duplicates
            unset($pair_A);
            unset($pair_B);
            $i++;
     } 
}
```

Any other suggestions or codes to make it easy?

Comment: You didn't specified either it is working fine and you need optimization tips or you code is not working.

Comment: and what if there is 3rd person aged 18?

Comment: codes to make it easy @IqbalMalik

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can do it all with one statement

```sql
INSERT INTO match_pairs (ID, Name, Age, PartnerID, PartnerName, PartnerAge)
SELECT m1.id, m1.name, m1.age,
       m2.id partnerid, m2.name partnername, m2.age partnerage
  FROM `match` m1 LEFT JOIN `match` m2
    ON m1.age = m2.age AND m1.id <> m2.id
 ORDER BY m1.id
```

Result is `match_pairs`:

```
+------+--------+------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| ID   | Name   | Age  | PartnerID | PartnerName | PartnerAge |
+------+--------+------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|    1 | Mary   |   18 |         2 | Edward      |         18 |
|    2 | Edward |   18 |         1 | Mary        |         18 |
|    3 | Jen    |   22 |      NULL | NULL        |       NULL |
+------+--------+------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5111/1)** demo
Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94816/1)** demo (*with more than two persons with the same age*)

---

On php side it boils down to

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO match_pairs (ID, Name, Age, PartnerID, PartnerName, PartnerAge)
        SELECT m1.id, m1.name, m1.age,
               m2.id partnerid, m2.name partnername, m2.age partnerage
          FROM `match` m1 LEFT JOIN `match` m2
            ON m1.age = m2.age AND m1.id <> m2.id
         ORDER BY m1.id";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); //TODO better error handling
}
```

Comment: hi @peterm, thanks for your great query it helps me and works great but how can i trap on the query if it gets a duplicate? In short, it will not match if it is already match or have a pair already.

Comment: @EdmarCruz You're quite welcome. If you feel like the answer was helpful and provided a solution to your original question please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** it.

Comment: @EdmarCruz Now to your follow-up question. Frankly it's not very clear what you meant by *...trap on the query if it gets a duplicate...*. Do you mean you want to avoid duplicates in the target table if you execute this query periodically? If so you need to elaborate a bit on how do you populate `match` table. Do you ever delete records from it etc?

Comment: If Mary is already paired to Edward. Mary will not be paired anymore to another rows that match to age 18